# Making the Jquery code only run if an element is on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some pretty repetitive code at the moment, which I'm looking to refactor once I have this problem solved.

I'm working on my portfolio, which uses the same HTML set up in each section - as that's the design I'm going for. But currently, when I click on `more info`, the JQuery code not only runs on the section that is visible in the viewport, but it also runs on the sections that aren't visible. The problem is that if I click on `more info` in the first section, then scroll down to the following section, I can see that the JQuery has also run on section two.

I know that my current code is set up to do this, but how can I improve it so that this doesn't occur going forward and if I can, make the code is less repetitive?

```js
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function() {
  return this.animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 500);
};

$.fn.slideToggle = function() {
  if ($("#one, #two, #three").attr("trigger") === "0") {
    return this.delay(200).animate({
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 200);
  } else {
    return this.animate({
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 200);
  }
};

$.fn.imageSlideToggle = function() {
  if ($("#one, #two, #three").attr("trigger") === "1") {
    return this.animate({
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 200);
  } else {
    return this.delay(200).animate({
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 200);
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#one-more").click(function() {
    if ($("#one").attr("trigger") === "0") {
      $(".image").imageSlideToggle();
      $(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();
      $("#one-more").html("Close");
      $("#one").attr("trigger", "1");
    } else {
      $(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();
      $(".image").imageSlideToggle();
      $("#one-more").html("More Info");
      $("#one").attr("trigger", "0");
    }
  });

  $("#two-more").click(function() {
    if ($("#two").attr("trigger") === "0") {
      $(".image").imageSlideToggle();
      $(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();
      $("#two-more").html("Close");
      $("#two").attr("trigger", "1");
    } else {
      $(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();
      $(".image").imageSlideToggle();
      $("#two-more").html("More Info");
      $("#two").attr("trigger", "0");
    }
  });

  $("#three-more").click(function() {
    if ($("#three").attr("trigger") === "0") {
      $(".image").imageSlideToggle();
      $(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();
      $("#three-more").html("Close");
      $("#three").attr("trigger", "1");
    } else {
      $(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();
      $(".image").imageSlideToggle();
      $("#three-more").html("More Info");
      $("#three").attr("trigger", "0");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 25px 45px 0 45px;
}

.contentcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header {
  font-family: Chivo;
}

.vertical-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.maincontentcontainer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: bottom;
  object-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 75%;
}

.image:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddencontent {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Lato;
  display: none;
  width: 70%;
}

.moreinfo {
  z-index: 10;
}

.moreinfo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#one {
  background-color: jetblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#two {
  background-color: steelblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

#three {
  background-color: ivory;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chivo|Lato:300,800,900|Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="one" class="container" trigger="0">
  <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="top header">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="maincontentcontainer">
      <img class="image vertical-center" src="https://www.perfectdailygrind.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Blending-specialty-coffee.jpg">
      <div class="hiddencontent vertical-center">
        <p>Etiam at neque justo. Integer id blandit nunc. Quisque semper feugiat sagittis. Cras pulvinar, justo ac posuere dapibus, neque erat finibus purus, in dapibus nisl ligula id magna. Vestibulum et scelerisque risus. Cras sed mi dictum, ultricies
          metus et, dignissim massa. Duis sed venenatis orci. Cras eleifend metus vitae sapien vehicula, ut sodales odio euismod. Proin porta consequat diam fringilla posuere. Phasellus nibh lectus, varius sit amet euismod ut, cursus a dui. Quisque vel
          lacus sit amet massa imperdiet laoreet eu in nibh.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom header">
      <h3 id="one-more" class="moreinfo">More Info</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="two" trigger="0">
  <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="top header white">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="maincontentcontainer">
      <img class="image vertical-center" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1183/8374/files/nathan-dumlao-325446_2048x2048.jpg?v=1506339381">
      <div class="hiddencontent vertical-center white">
        <p>Etiam at neque justo. Integer id blandit nunc. Quisque semper feugiat sagittis. Cras pulvinar, justo ac posuere dapibus, neque erat finibus purus, in dapibus nisl ligula id magna. Vestibulum et scelerisque risus. Cras sed mi dictum, ultricies
          metus et, dignissim massa. Duis sed venenatis orci. Cras eleifend metus vitae sapien vehicula, ut sodales odio euismod. Proin porta consequat diam fringilla posuere. Phasellus nibh lectus, varius sit amet euismod ut, cursus a dui. Quisque vel
          lacus sit amet massa imperdiet laoreet eu in nibh.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom header white">
      <h3 id="two-more" class="moreinfo">More Info</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="three" trigger="0">
  <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="top header">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="maincontentcontainer">
      <div class="maincontentcontainer">
        <img class="image vertical-center" src="https://www.perfectdailygrind.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/cappuccino-2.jpg">
        <div class="hiddencontent vertical-center">
          <p>Etiam at neque justo. Integer id blandit nunc. Quisque semper feugiat sagittis. Cras pulvinar, justo ac posuere dapibus, neque erat finibus purus, in dapibus nisl ligula id magna. Vestibulum et scelerisque risus. Cras sed mi dictum, ultricies
            metus et, dignissim massa. Duis sed venenatis orci. Cras eleifend metus vitae sapien vehicula, ut sodales odio euismod. Proin porta consequat diam fringilla posuere. Phasellus nibh lectus, varius sit amet euismod ut, cursus a dui. Quisque
            vel lacus sit amet massa imperdiet laoreet eu in nibh.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom header">
      <h3 id="three-more" class="moreinfo">More Info</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the class `.hiddenClass` to toggle text on and off. See lines with `$(".hiddencontent").slideToggle();` If you only want individual elements to be triggered then you should use id's for each section or you should get the specific target that was clicked. When a class is toggled every element with that class is toggled.

If you want your code to be less verbose, then you should make a class for each more info button then detect that class. Then when that class detects a click then you should toggle based on the target that triggered the event. Look at the docs for `.click` which triggers the toggle in your code: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector `$(".hiddenContent")` triggers for all elements in your html with that class, regardless of which container it is in. You can nest jquery selectors to make them more specific. For example: `$("#one .hiddenContent")` would select all elements with class 'hiddenContent' that are a child of an element with id 'one'

This is very similar in syntax but very different then this `$("#one.hiddenContent")` (notice the missing space) which would select all elements which have both id one AND the class hiddenContent

So to summarize: nesting two more or selectors in one jquery selector will narrow down the selection either hierarchical (parent -> child) or by the amount of qualities it must possess.